# %2B is converted into space on access through $_COOKIE

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting a cookie using `$.cookie`

```
$.cookie('enc_an', 'awgWTY5CnJr0f4WD0wU4HH+sAupxj459YNb7Q=', {path: '/'});
```

But when i echo it on other page it gives different Output

```
echo $_COOKIE['enc_an']; //Outputs : awgWTY5CnJr0f4WD0wU4HH sAupxj459YNb7Q=
```

when i inspect cookie Value it is `URL encoded`

```
awgWTY5CnJr0f4WD0wU4HH%2BsAupxj459YNb7Q=
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653252/why-is-this-2b-string-being-urldecoded

Comment: yes i may be duplicate but i cannot find answer or solution to this problem.. i have seen that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default the cookie value is encoded when writing using encodeURIComponent. This can be bypassed by setting by setting raw to true](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#configuration):

```
$.cookie.raw = true;
$.cookie('enc_an', 'awgWTY5CnJr0f4WD0wU4HH+sAupxj459YNb7Q=', {path: '/'});
```

Comment: if i dont want to use raw, can i get the string back

Comment: Without `raw=true` you would use `urldecode` on the PHP side of thing: `echo urldecode($_COOKIE['enc_an']);`

Comment: No i am not getting + back it is outputting space

Comment: `urldecode($_COOKIE['enc_an']) == "awgWTY5CnJr0f4WD0wU4HH+sAupxj459YNb7Q="` but its echo is showing space not + . Any ways i dont want to echo hence.. i got my solution. Thank You